# Auto-filter returns no row: skip next steps

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am building an exception report which highlights missing/inaccurate data after applying a series of auto-filters.
Problem:
1)when one of the autofilter returns no result / no rows, the colouring code apply colours to all the cells in the data range.
2) the report in some weeks there may have results / rows, some week auto-filter won't have any results / rows

Guidance Required: Looking at the code below, can anyone tell me if autofilter in BBB title doesn't return in a row, how can i skip the colouring/highlighting? Rather move to CCC titled filter.

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query__57")
          .Range.AutoFilter Field:=a, Criteria1:=Array("BCH", "HS", "L"), 
           Operator:=xlFilterValues
                
       'BBB 
          .Range.AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="Approved"

'if autofilter returns no result, i want to skip next this function
          .ListColumns(p).DataBodyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    
'start function here
          .Range.AutoFilter Field:=i
```

Comment: Mech : may I please request you to demonstrate what you mean? perhaps alter a group of my code

Comment: hard to do in comments and it's not an answer so I don't want to mislead future SO'ers. Join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216344/vba-wb-ws

Comment: unfortunately i don't have 20 reputations to chat. Any other way to communicate? Maybe use 'Answer  Question'

Comment: maybe someone else will also upvote you so you can :)

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of lines you get after applying the filter. If the result is 1, then ignore.

Lets assume filter is on Column B

```
Dim Visible_cells As Long
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Your condition", Operator:=xlAnd
Visible_cells = Range("B4:B1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count

If Visible_cells > 1 Then ' code will continue only if the visible cells is more than 1
    ' Continue your code
Else
End If
```

Comment: i am filtering let's header table named 'ID'  (column 2) in row 4 and find no result or row of data under the header? i need to skip colouring the the cells rgb 255. what should be the 'do something'?

Comment: unfortunately it is still colouring all the cells when there is no result of auto-filter. Could it be because of Datarange function i am using?